# Mint + Kernel 4.5.4: laptop loses suspend state when unplugged

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, power-management, suspend

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 on a newish Asus laptop with Mate desktop. To get the Nvidia graphics and Elan touchpad both to work, I installed the 4.5.4 Linux kernel. I've pretty much got everything working well.

The only problem I'm noticing is that when the laptop is suspended and I disconnect the power, it loses its state.

The battery is fully charged and the suspend / resume functionality works fine as long as the power is plugged in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, seemingly related to Asus laptops and coming and going depending on the Linux kernel and power settings:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108801

In this case it resolved itself after applying the 300 version of the Asus BIOS / UEI / firmware upgrade available on the Asus website. For an Asus ROG GL552VW laptop, at this writing that upgrade is found through the Asus.com support pages at:

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/GL552VW/GL552VW-AS300.zip

Answer (score 0):

I have three comments buried in that bugzilla thread. It turns out that there are two elements (at least for my machine) to resolving the problem.

1. As mentioned above, downgrading the BIOS often solves the problem. For me, I was able to downgrade the BIOS by booting in Windows and running the ASUS-provided Winflash program.
2. The problem seems to be related to Nvidia graphics drivers as well as the BIOS. For me, installing and running the nvidia-persistenced daemon needed to be done in conjunction with downgrading the BIOS. More on this at http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/